# ssh-add -D has no effect

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have several keys registered:

```
$ ssh-add -l
4096 cd:43:96:9e:0c:9a:38:ae:d9:96:f0:c5:d1:bf:9d:96 alex@sunny2 (RSA)
2048 4c:eb:fc:6b:ab:a0:ff:99:c3:ff:13:0a:95:2a:68:70 ███████ (RSA)
4096 01:cc:8d:c9:3c:ca:cf:39:93:57:e5:36:91:30:c2:94 ██████(RSA)
4096 87:b3:05:9a:68:6a:2b:be:1f:6f:ce:1b:34:50:c9:01 ██████████(RSA)
2048 37:d7:c6:08:65:9e:d4:8e:57:a2:05:36:71:e3:0b:13 ███ (RSA)
2048 3c:62:aa:4e:86:6d:83:b0:f7:b8:fb:0a:db:c4:67:3b ██████ (RSA)
1024 a4:1b:cb:c9:a0:99:19:80:67:e2:1b:14:5b:7e:17:cf ███████ (RSA)
```

I tried `ssh-add -d` ██████ to remove selectively,
and `ssh-add -D` to remove all keys.

this does not seem to work. After I executed `ssh-add -D`, the output of `ssh-add -l` is the same like before.

I tried, for example, `ssh-add -d alex@sunny2`, and also the full path to the key file, which is, in this example, `~/.ssh/alex_rsa`.

I also tried 'wildcard-remove', `ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/*`.

Interestingly I get a confirmation, that the key was removed:

```
Identity removed: .ssh/alex_rsa ( alex@sunny2)
```

But `ssh-add -l` afterwards again lists all the key files, so it seems there went something wrong while removing. Or, there is some mechanism which adds the keys immediately again.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 240

Host 192.168.0.107
        PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,password,publickey,hostbased,gssapi-with-mic

Host github.com
        HostName    github.com
        IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/alex_rsa
```

SSH version is:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Comment: I think specifying which key to remove only makes sense with `-d`, not `-D`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! When trying with `-d`, I get `Bad key file [..]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there may be a mechanism, that adds keys to your keyring. For example on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04LTS) I can see the following PAM configuration:

```
blafasel@localhost:~$ grep -R gnome_keyring /etc/pam.*
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
/etc/pam.d/gnome-screensaver:auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so 
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
/etc/pam.d/unity:auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

This means, if I start an X session with `lightdm` this session will have access to keys provided by `gnome-keyring-daemon`. These will normally include all keys inside `~/.ssh/` that are read on login.

Edit: If you run Ubuntu 16.04 or have some other system running gnome (validate by `ps ax|grep keyring`) you can use `gnome-keyring-properties` to switch of session integration. Then no more keys will be provided after the next login.

Comment: But it should be anyways possible to remove those keys?

Comment: I killed `gnome-keyring-daemon`, now no `ssh-add` available anymore. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

1. kill `gnome-keyring-daemon`

   $ ps ax | grep keyring
    1627 ?        SLl    0:01 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
   17218 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto keyring

   $ kill 1627
2. restart ssh

   $ eval $(ssh-agent)
3. now all identities removed

   $ ssh-add -l
   The agent has no identities.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OpenSSH (and thus ssh-add) do you have?

Mine works:

```
$ ssh-add -l
... user@host (RSA)
$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Comment: Mine is definitely not working. Is there any mechanism that would automatically re-add some keys?

Comment: I don't know what you have running on your host. Are the keys protected by passphrases?

Comment: Yes, they are pw-protected.